# Highchart - add "onclick event" for total value stackLabel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

This question is a follow up to [In high chart how to add event for label click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062016/in-high-chart-how-to-add-event-for-label-click)

Is there a way to make the total sum number (ie. 10,9, 11, 11, 8) 
as shown at http://jsfiddle.net/t07ok5v3/5/ clickable? (ie. add the same functionality to the "9" as the "Oranges" label).   What if there is only one number per column at the top representing the sum?   [image: Column chart with some drawing]
The following code was the code given in the answer to add the label click.

```
chart.xAxis[0].labelGroup.element.childNodes.forEach(function(label)
{
    label.style.cursor = "pointer";
    label.onclick = function(){
    alert('You clicked on '+this.textContent);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I have made the stackLabels all appear to be clickable (they now have cursor "pointer', see jsfiddle link below).  **Now I just need to add the actual functionality of the click event to the stackLabel.  Can someone help me with this?**

http://jsfiddle.net/w291/gc1fdd1v/

Note: I don't have access to jquery in the development environment I am using.

UPDATE 2: The answer to this other question seems to solve my problem [so far] (I will update the post with my solution if it works): [Click event on clicking on the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507099/click-event-on-clicking-on-the-graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, you can use `Custom Events` plugin. It will allow you to add custom events on various elements like axis labels, legend, etc.

Plugin Reference:
https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/trmks8p2/

Comment: Do you know if the `Custom Events` plugin currently works with `React-Highcharts`?

Comment: I did not test it but I do not see why it would not. You can try and test it by yourself.